# Debugging Excel VBA ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs

Tags: vba, excel

I'm not sure why a snip of VBA code I have isn't working - I'm hoping someone can help.

I'm simply trying to execute a ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs as part of a larger module, but it's erroring out.

Here's the snippet of code where the error is occurring:

```
LdrLastName = Right(wbCleaner.Sheets("Import Information").Range("$A$2"), Len(wbCleaner.Sheets("Import Information").Range("$A$2")) - Len(Left(wbCleaner.Sheets("Import Information").Range("$A$2"), LstNameSpacePos)))
ExptdQBInitialFileName = LdrLastName & " " & wbCleaner.Sheets("Import Information").Range("$D$2") 'produces "LastName AccountCode"

'ExptdQBFileName MsgBox's the full file path and file name (i.e. C:/Folder/Filename.xlsx)
ExptdQBFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=ExptdQBInitialFileName, FileFilter:="QB Export File *.xlsx (*.xlsx),")

If ExptdQBFileName <> "" And ExptdQBFileName <> "False" Then
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ExptdQBFileName, _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, _
        Password:="", _
        WriteResPassword:="", _
        ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
        CreateBackup:=False
End If
```

The error highlights everything within the If/End If statement. I've used this code before without issue. Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Just for sharing, different between thisworkbook and activeworkbook
http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/thisworkbook-vs-activeworkbook/

Answer (score 1):

File Format 52 is `xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled`, or an `xlsm` file.  If you are saving as an .xlsx file, I think the file format you want is `xlOpenXMLWorkbook`, which casts to a 51.

It's helpful to use the enumerations instead of the integers:

```
LdrLastName = Right(wbCleaner.Sheets("Import Information").Range("$A$2"), Len(wbCleaner.Sheets("Import Information").Range("$A$2")) - Len(Left(wbCleaner.Sheets("Import Information").Range("$A$2"), LstNameSpacePos)))
ExptdQBInitialFileName = LdrLastName & " " & wbCleaner.Sheets("Import Information").Range("$D$2") 'produces "LastName AccountCode"

ExptdQBFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=ExptdQBInitialFileName, FileFilter:="QB Export File (*.xlsx), *.xlsx,")

If ExptdQBFileName <> "" And ExptdQBFileName <> "False" Then
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ExptdQBFileName, _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, _
        Password:="", _
        WriteResPassword:="", _
        ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
        CreateBackup:=False
End If
```

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s5/win001.htm

Comment: Ah thank you! That didn't solve the problem, but definitely a fix that needed to help regardless. Any other ideas? I'll update my question above

Comment: Also, can you show the value of the `ExptdQBFileName` variable?

Comment: The error is: Run-time error '1004':  Method 'SaveAs' of object '_Workbook' failed                I'll add variable values above. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Got it. Not sure why but ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs had to be changed to ThisWorkbook.Sheets("QB Export File").SaveAs

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why but the solution was to change

```
ActiveWorkbook.("QB Export File").SaveAs
```

to

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("QB Export File").SaveAs
```

Thanks user2851376 for sharing the link below comparing ThisWorkbook vs. ActiveWorkbook
http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/thisworkbook-vs-activeworkbook/